# numpy concatenate function not works when handling with large matrix

Tags: numpy, concatenation

I was trying to concatenate a 3-by-n 3d coordinate matrix called VTrans with a 1-by-n all one value vector called lr to augment the coordinate matrix to the 4-by-n homogeneous matrix. n in my case is the vertex Number 141669, which is pretty big.

The code below is not working while it does work in a very small dataset.

```
lr = np.ones(vertexNum).reshape((1, vertexNum))
VtransAppend = np.concatenate((VTrans, lr), axis=0)
```

**update2:**

Just found the problem, my vertexNum is wrong! IT is actually 47223 instead of 141669. 141669 is its size! All solution work and I will accept the first one. Thank you all!

The error says "all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly"

I further verify lr and VtransAppend has the same length by printing the size out.

```
print lr.size
print VTrans.size
```

Anyone once has the same weird problem before and know how to solve it?

**Here is the update:**

My VTrans matrix is attached, where vertextNum is 141669 
[image: Giant Matrix]
This is the code followed by YXD's suggestion, but the issue still exits...

```
vertexNum = VTrans.size  # Total vertex in current model
lr = np.ones(vertexNum)
VtransAppend = np.concatenate((VTrans, lr.reshape(1, -1)), axis=0)
```

Comment: You should look at `shape` and not `size`, which refers only to the number of elements and not the dimensions. Tell us the shape of `lr` and of `VTrans` and this will be simple to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fiddle `lr` to have the same number of dimensions as `vTrans`

```
>>> n = 4
>>> vTrans = np.random.random_sample((3, n))
>>> lr = np.ones(n)
>>> np.concatenate((vTrans, lr.reshape(1, -1)), axis=0)
array([[ 0.65769116,  0.41008341,  0.66046706,  0.86501781],
       [ 0.51584699,  0.60601466,  0.93800371,  0.25077702],
       [ 0.16696658,  0.41839794,  0.0938594 ,  0.48484606],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ]])
>>>
```

i.e. after the reshape, the non-concatenation dimension matches `vTrans`

```
>>> lr.shape
(4,)
>>> lr.reshape(1, -1).shape
(1, 4)
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the problem is still there after using the code you recommend. I edit the question and attached my VTrans matrix there.

Answer (score 0):

Try `vstack` instead of `concatenate`:

```
a = np.random.random((3,5))
b = np.random.random(5)
np.vstack((a, b))
```

Alternatively:

```
np.concatenate((a, b[None,:]))
```

The `None` adds an axis to the 1D array `b`.